# Set up CakePHP in a subdirectory; Wordpress is installed in the root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I have been searching for a solution for 2 hours but nothing seems to work... here is my problem:

I have WordPress installed in the root (var/www).  So by going to http://www.geekderek.com, I see my wordpress site.

I put CakePHP in a subdirectory var/www/cakephp.  I want to be able to see my CakePHP app by going to: www.geekderek.com/cakephp.

However, currently this url just returns a Wordpress page saying "Content not found."

I believe this problem can be solved by modifying .htaccess in my root directory.  So here is my .htaccess: http://pastebin.com/sXJTRstB

As you can see, I added this line to the default WP .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule    ^cakephp(/(.*))?$ cakephp/app/webroot/$1    [QSA,L]
```

However, for some reason this doesn't seem to work.

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong??  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simmilar setup, that my cake app is in subdirectory, my root .htaccess has this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^cakephp/(.*)$ /cakephp/$1 [L,QSA]
```

All the rest is handled with the regular cakephp setup.

my /cakephp/app/webroot/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

hope this works for you too :)

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work for me.  I still keep getting a wordpress page...

Answer (score 0):

thanat's answer almost worked for me. i just had to edit the *RewriteBase* to read

```
RewriteBase /cakephp
```

and make sure apache conf allowed my root directory to override its previous options

```
<Directory "/my/root/dir">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

but then again, my *app* dir lies outside the *DocumentRoot* set by apache. and the *cakephp* dir is actually the *webroot* itself. so my dir structure is as follows

```
/my/root
/my/root/app  #cake's app dir without webroot
/my/root/dir  #apache DocumentRoot (your wordpress is here)
/my/root/dir/cakephp  #cake's webroot
```

also make sure to edit `/my/root/dir/cakephp/index.php` so it knows where the *app* and cake's library dirs are.

Answer (score 0):

This is my case, with laravel but they are the same.

> https://community.bitnami.com/t/laravel-application-in-subdirectory-of-wordpress-website/79535/2

Just need to change

```
AllowOverride None => AllowOverride All
```